# Question on refering to a position of an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am starting to learn c++ language and i would like to know if it is possible to refer to a position of an array using a position of another array.
example:

```
pos[x[3]] = 0;
```

Comment: Sure, why not? As long as `x[3]` is an integer.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But be aware that if you do it incorrectly you might get garbage or worse.

Comment: The index used for an array can be *any* valid expression that generates a valid index.

Answer (score 4):

So long as `x[3]` is an integral type or is implicitly convertible to an integral type, the code is syntactically valid. It's your job though to check if `3` is a valid index of the array `x`, and `x[3]` a valid index of `pos`.

For example, `pos[1.0]` is not allowed, as `1.0` is a `double`. (Annoyingly you can use a `double` type in the overloaded `[]` operator on `std::vector`.)

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.

Provided `x` is declared something like this:

```
int x[size];
unsigned int x1[size];
size_t x2[size];
```

Any of these should work. However, something like this will not:

```
std::string x3[size];
```

`x3` is an array of strings. C arrays don't have non-integer access. But any integer type should work fine.

---

P. S. If you ever want to use `std::string`s as away to access an array, you will want an [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) instead.